# Issue with using Jquery File Upload on MVC 4. Multiple calls to Action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to use  [jquery-file-upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html) on my MVC 4 application to upload multiple images to server.

I have followed this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bryansampica/archive/2013/01/15/AsyncMVCFileUpload.aspx) to implement image upload.

Here is my view :

```
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<style>
    body
    {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
</style>
<form action="/api/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
    <div class="span7">
        <div class="well">
            <i class="icon-plus"></i><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add files...</span>
            <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">
            <button id="btnUploadAll" class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="button">
                Upload All</button>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="bar" id="overallbar" style="width: 0%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span7">
        <div class="well hide" id="filelistholder">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span7">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
@section PageScripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/api/upload",
                limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
                sequentialUploads: true,
                progressInterval: 100,
                maxChunkSize: 10000,
                add: function (e, data) {
                    $('#filelistholder').removeClass('hide');
                    data.context = $('<div />').text(data.files[0].name).appendTo('#filelistholder');
                    $('</div><div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width:0%"></div></div>').appendTo(data.context);
                    $('#btnUploadAll').click(function () {
                        data.submit();
                    });
                },
                done: function (e, data) {
                    data.context.text(data.files[0].name + '... Completed');
                    $('</div><div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width:100%"></div></div>').appendTo(data.context);
                },
                progressall: function (e, data) {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    $('#overallbar').css('width', progress + '%');
                },
                progress: function (e, data) {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
   }
```

And here is api controller:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.IO;

namespace MvcTesting.Controllers.WebApi
{
    public class UploadController : ApiController
    {
        // Enable both Get and Post so that our jquery call can send data, and get a status
        [HttpGet]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
        {
            // Get a reference to the file that our jQuery sent.  Even with multiple files, they will all be their own request and be the 0 index
            HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

            // do something with the file in this space 
             var uniqueFileName = GlobalVariables.UniqueFileNameGenerator(file.FileName);
        var path = GlobalVariables.UniqueFilePath(uniqueFileName, "~/Data/ObjectImages");
        file.SaveAs(path);

        var objImg = new ObjectImage
                         {
                             ObjectID = objectID,
                             ImageDescription = form.Get("ImageDescription"),
                             ImageFilePath = path,
                             ImageFileName = uniqueFileName,
                             ContentType = file.ContentType,
                             CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
                         };
        currentObject.ObjectImages.Add(objImg);
        _context.SaveChanges();
            // end of file doing

            // Now we need to wire up a response so that the calling script understands what happened
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = new { name = file.FileName };

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(result));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;

            // For compatibility with IE's "done" event we need to return a result as well as setting the context.response
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the problem that the method gets called many times (around 12 times when I debug it) instead of only one. As a result I get 12 entries in the database instead of one entry.

I am expecting the action to be called only the number of files that I am uploading. Or this is the way that it can keep track of the user interface up to date?

If that is the case how can I fix my code?

Is there a way of checking the content of the request and comparing it with the previous content and if the content is the same do nothing if the content is different then save it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
maxChunkSize: 10000,
```

Because it is breaking the file up into chunks, the api is called multiple times for the same file.  If you remove the maxChunkSize, it will only make one call.  However, it will also mean you are limited to the size of file you can upload, but for images, you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
    {
        // Get a reference to the file that our jQuery sent.  Even with multiple files, they will all be their own request and be the 0 index
        HttpPostedFile file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

        //// do something with the file in this space 
        //// ....
        //// end of file doing

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{\"name\":\"" + file.FileName + "\",\"type\":\"" + file.ContentType + "\",\"size\":\"" + file.ContentLength + "\"}");
        return null;
    }
```